# TextBox validation sets Button border to red

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an `ItemsControl` where I dynamically create a new `GroupBox` with several controls in it and model behind. That works so far. I've also implemented validation to my `TextBox`es, which is also working as intended. And there is a `Button` to remove this `GroupBox`, which binds to the `Ancestor` of type `UserControl`.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding StorageLocationList, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GroupBox Style="{StaticResource GroupBoxBase}">
                <GroupBox.Header>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="ExportGroupCheckBox" Content="Storage Location active" IsChecked="{Binding GroupActive, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxBase}" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ActivateExportCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}"/>
                </GroupBox.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ExportGroupCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Name:" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource LimitedCharTextBox}" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Storage Location:" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" IsReadOnly="True" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBox}" Text="{Binding StorageLocationPath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"/>
                        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="Browse..." VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Command="{Binding StorageLocationBrowseCommand}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonBase}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Canvas>
                        <Button Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Right="0" Content="X" ToolTip="Remove Group" Style="{StaticResource RemoveButton}" Command="{Binding ElementName=GPUserControl, Path=DataContext.RemoveStorageLocationGroupCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

When I now type something wrong in the `TextBox` that is bound to the `Name` property, the validation takes place and the `TextBox` receives a red border to indicate that. Cool. But the button to remove this `GroupBox` also gets a red border. And that's weird.

I also tried to set the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` of the `Button` to `null` like so:

```
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
```

but that sets the `TextBox` `Validation.ErrorTemplate` to `null` as well.

So how are they connected to each other? Somehow through the `UserControl`?

Here is a screenshot of it:
[image]

**EDIT:**
Here are the `Styles`:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="GroupBoxBase" TargetType="GroupBox">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ConfigurationMainWindownButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="70"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,2,2"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="RemoveButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ConfigurationMainWindownButton}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <!-- <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/> -->
</Style>
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes your styles.

Comment: @mm8 is that enough for a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>  it sets in RemoveButton style. It might be not related with Validate state

Comment: @OlegBondarenko `Foreground` is setting the text color of the `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

WPF marks all your ItemsControl as not valid not only your text box inside due to using  the same data model (actually model is not valid - not controls) . Text box just set state to invalid value. You could resolve it with overriding  Validation.ErrorTemplate style setting for Remove Group button  control if the button have to ignore validate state of model .

```
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">

        <Setter.Value>

            <ControlTemplate>

                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>

    </Setter>
```